# Calculating average time using TimeSpans in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to calculate an average time by subtracting end time by start time then dividing the difference by a count. In my case the count is products scanned. I want to output the result in a string using this format "HH:mm:ss". I have been playing around with my code but I can't get it to work.

Here are my variables:

```
    private DateTime woStartTime;
    private DateTime woEndTime;
    private TimeSpan difference;
    private long average;
```

Here is the value for Start Time

```
    woStartTime = DateTime.Now;
```

Here is my method for calculating average time

```
 public void Calculate_Average_Time()
    {
        try
        {
            woEndTime = DateTime.Now;
            difference = woEndTime - woStartTime;
            long dTime = Convert.ToInt64(difference.Ticks);
            average = dTime / Scanned;
            DateTime aTimeS = Convert.ToDateTime((average / 86400M).ToString("HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            lblError.Text = aTimeS.ToString(); // display to verify results
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I keep getting an exception error: string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0.

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use `DateTime` at all. Use [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead when you want to accurately measure elapsed time.

I'll answer your question in terms of `DateTime` anyway, hoping that'll be helpful for you in the future :) You don't need to first convert to string, then convert to DateTime. Use

```
TimeSpan aTimeS = new TimeSpan(average);
```

This will create a new `TimeSpan` with the specified number of ticks. Note the usage of `TimeSpan` rather than `DateTime`.`TimeSpan` represents an amount of time, while `DateTime` is a specific point in time.

Comment: I won't post it here, but you can check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx or http://www.dotnetperls.com/stopwatch.

Comment: Can you pass a stop watch between methods? I need to start the stop watch in one method and stop it in another.

Comment: Sure. Why shouldn't you be able to?

Answer (score 0):

Using DateTime is not the correct way. You have ticks as the average which may not correspond to a DateTime. Use TimeSpan instead as shown below:

```
        try
        {
            woEndTime = DateTime.Now;
            difference = woEndTime - woStartTime;
            long dTime = Convert.ToInt64(difference.Ticks);
            average = dTime / Scanned;
            TimeSpan averageTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(average);                
            lblError.Text = averageTimeSpan.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"); // display to verify results

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Note: The format for TimeSpan differs from DateTime formats. You need to escape the colons.